# How to fix "if statements" in "return part" of class component in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I am new to react. I want to return components on the basis of multiple conditions. But in this code in return section if statements are not working and I'm getting error. How can I fix that?

```
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.filterField);
        const filteredXpGreater = this.state.peoples.filter(person => {
            return person.randomXp > 3;
        })
        const filteredXpLess = this.state.peoples.filter(person => {
            return person.randomXp <= 3;
        })
        return (
            if (this.state.filterField.includes("Above 3 Years of Experience")) {
                <div className='App'>
                <Filter radioSelected1={this.onRadioSelected1} radioSelected2={this.onRadioSelected2} checkedMale={this.onCheckedMale} checkedFemale={this.onCheckedFemale} />
                <Cardlist data={filteredXpGreater} />
            </div>
            } else if (this.state.filterField.includes("Above 3 Years of Experience") {
                <div className='App'>
                <Filter radioSelected1={this.onRadioSelected1} radioSelected2={this.onRadioSelected2} checkedMale={this.onCheckedMale} checkedFemale={this.onCheckedFemale} />
                <Cardlist data={filteredXpLess} />
            </div>
            } else {
                <div className='App'>
                <Filter radioSelected1={this.onRadioSelected1} radioSelected2={this.onRadioSelected2} checkedMale={this.onCheckedMale} checkedFemale={this.onCheckedFemale} />
                <Cardlist data={this.state.peoples} />
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just JavaScript, and in JavaScript an `if` statement is not an expression, so you can't return its value.

You can either lift the `if` out of the `return`:

```
        if (this.state.filterField.includes("Above 3 Years of Experience")) {
            return <div className='App'>
                <Filter radioSelected1={this.onRadioSelected1} radioSelected2={this.onRadioSelected2} checkedMale={this.onCheckedMale} checkedFemale={this.onCheckedFemale} />
                <Cardlist data={filteredXpGreater} />
            </div>
        } else if () {
            return <div className='App'>
                <Filter radioSelected1={this.onRadioSelected1} radioSelected2={this.onRadioSelected2} checkedMale={this.onCheckedMale} checkedFemale={this.onCheckedFemale} />
                <Cardlist data={this.state.peoples} />
            </div>
        }
```

(You probably meant `else` instead of `else if()` here, but I left it as is.)

Or use the ternary conditional operator `... ? ... : ...`:

```
    return (
        this.state.filterField.includes("Above 3 Years of Experience") ?
            <div className='App'>
                <Filter radioSelected1={this.onRadioSelected1} radioSelected2={this.onRadioSelected2} checkedMale={this.onCheckedMale} checkedFemale={this.onCheckedFemale} />
                <Cardlist data={filteredXpGreater} />
            </div>
            :
            <div className='App'>
                <Filter radioSelected1={this.onRadioSelected1} radioSelected2={this.onRadioSelected2} checkedMale={this.onCheckedMale} checkedFemale={this.onCheckedFemale} />
                <Cardlist data={this.state.peoples} />
            </div>
    )
```

Not sure if you need any extra parentheses somewhere; my JSX is a bit rusty.

Comment: I have more than two conditions. How can I use ternary? I edit my code so please review your answers.

Comment: You can chain them naturally without extra parentheses: `A ? resultIfA : B ? resultIfB : resultIfNeitherANorB`. At that point I'd rather choose the more readable `if`/`else` chain though.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use ternary if in render:

```
return (

 <>
   // ... some code 

   { condition ? trueOutput: falseOutput }

   { 
     this.state.filterField.includes("Above 3 Years of Experience")
       ? <> true case </>
       : <> false case </>
   }

   // ... some other code
 </>

)
```